# JQuery - Get .x .y coords of a <p>Too much overflow!</p> and then move a <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coordinates, move

Html

```
<div id="video"></div>
<p class="coordspls">Too much overflow!</p>
```

Pseudo Code:

```
Get x position of .coordspls save to cox
Get y position of .coordspls save to coy

Set x position of #video to cox
Set y position of #video to coy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) takes a setter as well, the same object format as it returns, so you can do this:

```
$("#video").css({ position: 'absolute' }).offset($("p.coordspls").offset());
```

[You can give it a try here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/eF3xK/), all this does it make sure the position is `absolute` (remove the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) call if this is already the case), then sets the `top` and `left` to match.

Comment: this looks interesting may I fit it the way that works for me - thx

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't work like that, luckily.
To put #video at the same location of coordpls, you will have to move it inside coordspls when some condition occurs and use position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px and make sure the surrounding p has a relative position.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = $("#coordspls").offset().left;
var y = $("#coordspls").offset().top;

console.log('x: ' + x + ' y: ' + y);
```

Thats as far as i got! sorry but hope it gives you a starting point!